# Can i merge icon with executable application in linux?

Tags: linux, executable

if you made up an application in linux you will get a blank ugly icon
but if i wanted to add an icon without going and make a desktop entry , is it possible ?
if i uploaded my portable app to the internet i would like that users see the icon merged to my portable app ! :)
Thanks

Comment: What kind of application, in the first place? A compiled executable or a script?

Comment: @MichałGórny: out of curiosity, does it matter? Is there e.g. a standard ELF section for the icon that modern desktops use?

Comment: @thkala: I would guess not but I would have to check. While if that were a script, I could say 'no' already. Also, for an compiled executable I wouldn't hesitate to mention it's probably not going to be portable at all.

Answer (score 0):

For scripts probably not, but for ELF binaries seen under Gnome (nautilus) you can try 
[elfres](http://www.compholio.com/elfres/)
http://www.compholio.com/elfres/

Answer (score 0):

Most desktop environments on Linux follow the [freedesktop.org Desktop Entry Specification](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec) for application descriptions and icons.  You'll need a separate `.desktop` file in one of the [XDG directories](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/basedir-spec) (specifically, `applications` within one of `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`) which will list an [icon](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/icon-theme-spec) (which is an image file in another directory).